# Reading only float values from text file

Tags: c++, arrays, filestreams

I have a data file which is text format. It has 2 coloums first one is not useful that I could ignore it and second one is that what I need. The coloum has a different values on each row as string, float etc. For some calculation I need to only float members of this coloum. I followed that way, first declare a float array and read values and save the array with **">>"** basic command.

Problem is when non-float row has came, reading function works as broken. It reads non-float values as "0" and save as that. It's OK but after that reads whole values as "0" even if it was a float.

Datafile.txt (example)

```
aa 1.1
bb 2.2
cc 3.0
dd somestring
ee 4.3
ff 4.9
```

Code (example)

```
 do 
{
    dfile >> a >> dat[i]; 
    ofile << dat[i]<<endl;
    cout << dat[i]<<endl;
    i++;

}while(dfile.eof());
```

Output file (example)

```
1.1
2.2
3.0
0
0
0
..goes
```

I've thought two ways to solve the problem. First one is skipping non-float rows. Second one is reading row in a period. Because float values listed in a sequence.

Comment: You could skip non float rows quite easily if you know which rows they are; You could add a condition in your loop that checks if you are on that line.

Comment: I'd read the 2 columns in as 2 strings, and then attempt the conversion.  Well, more accurately I wouldn't use a data format that involves the data type of a column changing, but if I couldn't change that, then I'd read and post process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read a string first, then attempt to convert to a number:

```
std::string maybeNumber;
while (dfile >> a >> maybeNumber)
{

    std::istringstream is(maybeNumber);
    float number = 0.0f;
    if (is >> number)
    {
        dat[i] = number;
        i++;
    }    
}
```

(You don't want to use `eof`. Everyone thinks they want to use `eof`, but it's almost always not what they need. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for details.)

Answer (score 1):

> It's OK but after that reads whole values as "0" even if it was a float.

You haven't shown your full code, but this sounds like the input stream is in an error state after the first non-parseable floating-point number, so it stops reading anything at all.

As for a solution to the problem,  read every line as a `std::string`, then split the line into a `std::vector<std::string>`. If the vector doesn't contain two elements or if the second one is not a `double`, do nothing, else process the row.

Something like this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(dfile, line))
{
    auto const elements = parse(line);
    if (size(elements) == 2 && is_double(elements[1]))
    {
        // process
    }
}
```

Now that you have solved the problem on the higher abstraction level, all you have to do is [implement something like `parse`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tokenize%20string%20c%2B%2B) and [implement something like `is_double`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+check+if+string+double) (divide & conquer).

Also note that the default C++ floating-point type is `double` and not `float`. When in doubt, use `double`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an algorithm like this:

For each line in the file:

1. Split the string by whitespaces
2. For each result of this split:

   1. Macht with regex "^\d+(\.\d+)?$"
   2. If string matches regex, convert to float and save in result array

Comment: Your regex doesn't take locales into account. Consider a system where `,` is used instead of `.`.

Comment: The OPs file seem to contain just `.` as deciaml sign. I consider changing `\.` to `,` as trivial if needed. Localisation also doesn't seem to be the topic of this question.

Answer (score 1):

using **getline** and **regex_token_iterator**

```
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v;
    std::regex reg("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    const char* filename="myfile.txt";

    std::ifstream ifs(filename,std::ios::binary);

    for(std::string s;std::getline(ifs,s);)
       for(std::sregex_token_iterator rgi(s.begin(),s.end(),reg);rgi!=std::sregex_token_iterator();++rgi)
         v.push_back(std::stof(rgi->str());

    std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout," ");
    return 0;
}
```